# Change a sigle value in an array of objects using useState in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, use-state

I'm following a React course and I'm trying to do some experiments around the code to have a better understanding of concepts.

I have some dummy data:

```
export const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'john' },
  { id: 2, name: 'peter' },
  { id: 3, name: 'susan' },
  { id: 4, name: 'anna' },
];
```

and this is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { data } from "../../../data";

const UseStateArray = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState(data);

  return (
    <>
      {people.map((person) => {
        const { id, name } = person;
        return (
          <div key={id} className="item">
            <h4>{name}</h4>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn"
        onClick={() => setPeople([])}
      >
        Clear Items
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default UseStateArray;
```

The button has an event handler on click which calls setPeople with an empty array (so to remove all of the elements).

I was trying to change the funcionality of such button, trying to change the name of the first element of my array of objects (data) in the following way:

```
onClick={() => setPeople(people[0].name = 'Frank')}
```

Doing this, get an error, namely: "TypeError: people.map is not a function".
I think the reason is because I'm not returning an array anymore and therefore `map` fails to run.

How can I simply change the name (or any value) of an object present in an array?

Comment: `setPeople([{...people[0], name: "Frank"}, ...people.slice(1)])`

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the object

```
clickHandler = () => {
   const newPeople = people.map((person, index) => {
       if (index === 0) {
            return {
                ...person,
                name: 'Frank'
            }
        }

        return person;
   });
  
   setPeople(newPeople);
}
....
....
onClick={clickHandler}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to copy the array into a newer version.
2. Extract the object out of the array using the index property.
3. Update the field.

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    { name: "Hello", id: 1 },
    { name: "World", id: 2 }
  ]);

  function changeName(idx) {
    const newData = [...data];
    newData[idx].name = "StackOverFlow";
    setData(newData);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((d, idx) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{d.name}</p>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                changeName(idx);
              }}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

NOTE :-

Mutation is not allowed on the state, which basically means you cannot change the state directly. Copy the object or an array and do the updates.

Comment: Good answer, i think `data[idx].name = "StackOverFlow";` should be `newData[idx].name = "StackOverFlow";`

Comment: Bingo! Corrected.